# como ocultar completamente un elemento al recargar la pagina con JS?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Estoy ocultando un div con la funcion hide() y si funciona, el problema es que al actualizar varias veces el navegador se ve el div por un pequeno instante solamente, quiero evitar eso, que completamente no aparezca, gracias

Comment: ¿Te ha servido mi ayuda?, o aún no.

Comment: por qué por hide? por que no renderizar el html con una clase oculta? o sin el div directamente? depende de algo en el backend?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar en tu javascript una funcion que contenga el html:

```
<div id="myDIV">Ocultar</div>
```

y el javascript

```
document.getElementById("myDIV").style.display = "none";
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes ponerle estilos css al iniciar y después de iniciar lo ocultas y le remueves el estilo.
Algo así:

```
<div id="mi_div" style="visibility: hidden;"></div>
```

Y en el código haces esto:

```
$('#mi_div').removeAttr('style');
$('#mi_div').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Si el div no tiene ninguna condición para que se muestre o no cuando se carga la página, lo mejor es inicializar el div en `style="display:none"`